# Elimination of blocks program

Tags: c++, algorithm, design-patterns, multidimensional-array

I was at a technical discussion earlier this morning and the chairperson invited me to play a game with him.

There are a sequence of 'n' blocks, every player on his chance could choose 2 adjacent blocks and mark them as filled. The players continue to do this until the last pair of adjacent blocks is filled. The person filling the last pair loses the game.

Question: I was later asked if I could build a program on C++ that would provide hints to every player at each chance to identify which of the available pairs would give him the maximum chances of winning considering the current status of the board.

I'm sure there is a design / algotithm for this. Just that I'm not able to identify it. Can you please help me with a possible way of approaching the problem. Is there an established problem that covers something similar (like the partition problem)

Comment: It sounds like this is isomorphic to a game where you have a pile of N objects, and each turn you must remove two objects from a pile, and may optionally split that pile into two smaller piles. The player who can't remove two objects wins. Pile games are usually amenable to memoization and dynamic programming approaches, so I'd start there.

Comment: So you want the winning chance of the best pair in each turn? Or the chances of all possible pairs in each turn?

Comment: @DanielJour thanks for taking a look. I want to suggest to the user which block he should choose at each step so he gets closer to winning. In a way with every chance he should get closer to leaving just 1 pair of boxes for the opponent to fill in.

Comment: For two players with perfect strategies, there's no such thing as "chance" when it comes to these kind of deterministic no-randomness full-information games. A particular move will either force a win for you, or an ensuing counter-move will force a win for your opponent. The only time chance enters the picture is when you play against imperfect humans, at which point it's more a problem of psychology than probability.

Comment: @Kevin thanks for your suggestion about pile games, by chance I meant if there are 10 adjacent blocks neither my move nor my opponent's subsequent move would end the game but both should be choosing the 2 boxes that would ensure they're not left with the last pair on the board.

Comment: If we have the blocks `1 2 3 4`, and the first player fills `2 3`, must the next one fill `1 4`, or is he stuck and therefore the first player has lost because he filled last?

Comment: @IVlad First player has lost because he filled in 2,3. Every time a player chooses, he is allowed to fill only adjacent blocks and the blocks are not cyclic (first and last cannot form a pair)

Answer (score 0):

I think that we can use dynamic programming. Let:

```
dp[n, 1] = true    if player 1 has a certain winning strategy for n blocks
           false   otherwise

dp[n, 2] = same for player 2
```

Where player 1 moves first.

We have:

```
dp[0, 1] = dp[0, 2] = true
dp[1, 1] = dp[1, 2] = true
dp[2, 1] = false, dp[2, 2] = true
```

Then the recurrence considers the current player taking the first and second blocks, the second and third etc. This means that the opponent will have to deal with two piles of sizes:

```
0, n - 2
1, n - 3
2, n - 4
...

k, n - k - 2, k = 0 to n - 2
```

For a player to win, they must have a winning strategy for at least one of the resulting piles.

For the current player to win, he must be able to get the opponent to a state for which their `dp` is `false`. So we have:

```
dp[n, 1] =       OR         {NOT (dp[k, 2] OR dp[n - k - 2, 2])} 
           0 <= k <= n - 2

dp[n, 2] =       OR         {NOT (dp[k, 1] OR dp[n - k - 2, 1])} 
           0 <= k <= n - 2
```

Meaning that `dp[n, 1]` is true iff we can get the next player into a state from which he has no certain winning strategy. Of course, our opponent will also play optimally.

```
dp[k, 2] OR dp[n - k - 2, 2]
```

Returns true if player 2 has a winning strategy for the two piles. If yes, we don't want to choose that, so we negate it, which returns false. If no, by negating it we get true, and by `OR`ing all values, we find out if there's a true, which we can pick.

Comment: Thanks ever so much for the detail. Will try implementing the logic and see if I'm able to find closure for this problem. I'm not able to use the vote button as this is my first post on stack overflow and have not built enough reputation. :(

Comment: @Vish308 it's all right. Please let me know if it works or not. Good luck!

Comment: There's at least a small mistake, because I'm assuming that the two piles are independent subproblems. But they're not, and it's also fine if you win just one of the subproblems. So we should replace the AND with OR in the formulas. I'm not entirely sure it's correct anyway, but I'll leave it up for now.

Comment: I'm thinking it might be possible for a player to skip a move on a certain pile by temporarily focusing on other piles, which might help him globally. I'm not sure if this is a valid concern for this solution or not, maybe someone else can comment on that.

Comment: sure will within the next couple of days. Thanks again for paying close attention. :)